# Get client host name or pc name from ip address

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net, active-directory

With this C# code in ASP.NET, I can get user name that is registered in Active Directory:

```
 var addlist = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
 string usernameClient= addlist.HostName.ToString();
```

This code returns the user name like `aaaa@aaa.net`.

How is the equivalent of this code in the node js?

How can get dns name client ?

Comment: It looks like you're retrieving the hostname of the computer that's connected, not the username. Perhaps they match, but what if someone logs into a different computer? Are you trying to utilize Windows Authentication in your app?

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get host name from ip address client.

```
require('dns').reverse(req.connection.remoteAddress.toString().replace("::ffff:", ""), function (err, hostnames) {
              
      if (!err) {
        PC_NAME = hostnames.toString().replace('.iasc.net', '');

      }
      else console.log(err)    
    });
```